# AWS SDK Java version 2 - is there an equivalent to doesObjectExist() from ver 1?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

The S3 client in the AWS Java SDK ver 1 had a method to check for the existence of an object in a bucket

```
doesObjectExist(bucketName, objectName)
```

In version 2 of the SDK I don't see anything similar but I wanted to see if I was missing anything.

The only idea I had was to attempt to use

`S3Client.getObject(GetObjectRequest)` 
which will throw a NoSuchKeyExcecption if the object doesn't exist.  I hate to use an exception like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please see s3 client service changes - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/docs/LaunchChangelog.md#4-service-changes

headObject is the 2.0 equivalent operation

Comment: but i checked headObject method implementation and it is simply throwing unsupported operation exception.

Comment: You need to check the concrete implementation of the S3Client (usuallly DefaultS3Client).